# Selecting rows with a string index that contains a bracket

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

My table `review_cp` is indexed on beer names. I got the top three beer names through the following code.

```
top_3_spacy = review_cp.groupby('Name')['Average Evaluation Score'].mean().sort_values(by='Average Evaluation Score', ascending = False).index[:3].tolist()
```

The results are `['Rodenbach Caractère Rouge', 'Dorothy (Wine Barrel Aged)', 'Doubleganger']`

However, when I tried to select rows using `review_cp.loc[top_3_spacy[0]]`, it gave me a key error.

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2896             try:
> -> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2898             except KeyError:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()
>
> KeyError: 'Rodenbach Caractère Rouge'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 review_cp.loc[top_3_spacy[0]]
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> **getitem**(self, key)    1422     1423             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
> -> 1424             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)    1425     1426     def _is_scalar_access(self, key:
> Tuple):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)    1848         # fall thru to straight lookup    1849         self._validate_key(key, axis)
> -> 1850         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)    1851     1852
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> _get_label(self, label, axis)
> 158             raise IndexingError("no slices here, handle elsewhere")
> 159
> --> 160         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
> 161
> 162     def _get_loc(self, key: int, axis: int):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key,
> axis, level, drop_level)    3735             loc, new_index =
> self.index.get_loc_level(key, drop_level=drop_level)    3736
> else:
> -> 3737             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)    3738     3739             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2897                 return
> self._engine.get_loc(key)    2898             except KeyError:
> -> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2900
> indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
> 2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()
>
> KeyError: 'Rodenbach Caractère Rouge'

---

I tried another method using `review_cp[review_cp['Name'].str.contains(top_3_spacy[0])]`, it worked for 'Rodenbach Caractère Rouge' and 'Doubleganger', but not for 'Dorothy (Wine Barrel Aged)'. I wonder if it was because of the bracket?

Comment: Can you please put full error message? It would Help to understand issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the issue is due to the bracket, as it is part of the string. As long as the string matches a name in the "Name" column, there shouldn't be a problem. If you want to get the rows of your top 3 list, instead of using loc, you can use:

```
review_cp[review_cp['Name'].isin(top_3_spacy)]
```

That will isolate your top3 names (and it should include Dorothy).

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the problem is, that `Name` is not in your index. Otherwise, your groupby statement would not be able to access the value. So your index is most likely an automatic integer index.
But `.loc` expects values in the index and can't find the name in the index of your DataFrame.

You can resolve this by using an indexer like in the post of DDD1.

`review_cp['Name'].isin(top_3_spacy)`

Creates this indexer to select the rows with the names in the list.